# What privilege should I grant to ApplicationPoolIdentity to be able to send emails

Tags: asp.net, iis, smtp

I have the following piece of code to send an email in my web application:

```
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("frommail.com@xxxxx","tomail@xxxx.com");
    mail.Subject = "Hi";
    mail.Body = "Hello";
    mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("172.16.0.4", 25);
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("frommail", "password");
    client.Send(mail);
```

When I run the application on the development server there's no problem in sending the mail. But when I try the application installed on the IIS I get "Generic error occured..." error. I'm 99 percent sure that this has something to do with the permissions as the development server is run under the  logged in account credentials and my account is the member of Administrators group,so it has access to anywhere.
 But I can't understand what account I should grant what privilege in order to get this working in IIS. The Identity of the Application Pool is ApplicationIdentity.

EDIT: I've set up the IIS on the same machine where I develop.

Comment: Does your webserver have access to the smtp server you are defining? I've had this issue before and in my case it was the firewall blocking the communication between webserver and smtp

Comment: or are you running them on the same server?

Comment: I develop on the same machine where my IIS stands. It's the same machine where it's working when run on development server (the default VS one) and does not work when tried on IIS.

Comment: Have you configured an SMTP server with IIS? You need to install this separately unlike IIS Express that has it build in.

Comment: I have SMTP feature installed. I say that because I can see the option in the Features View and can edit it.

Comment: One sec let me check my configuration

Comment: When you check your IIS, in SMTP E-mail what settings are ticked/selected?

Comment: Also what IIS version are you running? As I believe version 7 doesn't have SMTP anymore, you will need to install the IIS 6.0 version

Comment: Email adress:frommail@xxxxxx; Deliver e-mail to SMTP server, SMTP Server: 172.16.0.4;Port:25; Authentication Settings, Specify Credentials: frommail

Comment: Hmm that looks good to me, which version of IIS?

Comment: Also can you check again under Features View and see if SMTP is ticked under IIS 6?

Comment: The version of IIS is 7. The OS is Windows 7

Comment: Sorry I have no ideas left, I was running Windows 2008R2...